# Multiple Methods with variables

Tags: java, methods

I need the radius from the first one but it doesn't recognize it, how can I do it? By the way, there must be two methods, and second method must use the radius of the first one.

```
    public static double areaCircle(double rad) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter radius : ");

        rad = input.nextDouble();

        double circ = Math.PI*Math.pow(rad, 2);

        return circ;

        }

    public static double volumeCylinder (double h) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter height : ");

        h = input.nextDouble();

        double cyl = Math.PI*Math.pow(rad, 2)*h;
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like you've misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: Take the scanners out of the functions and assign them to variables. Then pass the variables into the functions. Use the return value from the first function in your second function.

Comment: Why do you have rad/h as method parameters and also taking rad/h as inputs! Do one of the two!!

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't get info about that variable. You have to pass value

```
public static double areaCircle(double rad) {



    double circ = Math.PI*Math.pow(rad, 2);

    return circ;

    }

public static double volumeCylinder (double h, double rad) { //added double rad



    double cyl = Math.PI*Math.pow(rad, 2)*h;
}
```

And when you call it from main

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter radius : ");
rad = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter h: ");
h= input.nextDouble();
double something = volumeCylinder(h,rad);
double something = areaCircle(rad);
```

Comment: What should I write write to the something parts? By the way, it again says,  h and rad cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: something is name of your variable you chose what name u want. Did you declare h and rad before this code? double rad and double h ?

Comment: Thank you I solved it, I forgot to declare it as you said :D